# a complete space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Define a set
$$X=\left\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}|f \mbox{ is n-times continuously differentiable}\right\}$$
equipped with the norm
$$||y||=\max_{\begin{subarray}{l}
                             0\le i\le n   \\
                             x\in \mathbb{R}
        \end{subarray}}\left|y^{(i)}(x)\right|,
 $$
where $n$ is a fixed positive number.
Is $X$ a complete space? If it is not, please give me a counter example.

I know that the space$\left\{f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}|f \mbox{ is n-times continuously differentiable}\right\}$ with the above norm is complete, but it seems that if the interval is unbounded, the situation is different.

Comment: What is $I$ in the expression $x\in I$? The unit interval? Or do you mean $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @MPW, i am sorry, it is a  typing error

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking that for all $n$, $$X(n)=\left\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}|f \mbox{ is n-times continuously differentiable}\right\}$$ is compact?

Comment: This isn't a well-defined norm. $f(x)=x$ is in $X$, but $||f||$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I agree with MPW; firstly, is it a norm ?

Comment: At the very least, you must replace "$\max$" by "$\sup$" since it is taken over a noncompact space. Then you may want to restrict $X$ to functions for which this purported norm is finite. I think now you see why the compact interval $[a,b]$ was used in the first place.

Comment: @MPW, so is it a generalized complete metric space?the norm of generalized metric space  can be infinite.